# querying data of a day for a person

Tags: ms-access

I have a table lke this:

```
name      date/time
======    ===================
Alan      2014-1-1 1:20
Alan      2014-1-1 1:30
Alan      2014-1-1 1:46
Alan      2014-1-2 1:40
Alan      2014-1-2 2:46
Alan      2014-1-2 3:00
Alan      2014-1-2 4:00
Mary      2014-1-1 12:10
Mary      2014-1-1 12:20
Mary      2014-1-2 12:10    
Mary      2014-1-2 13:00
Mary      2014-1-2 14:00
```

I want to have a query that only list a row daily, for example:

```
Alan      2014-1-1 1:20
Alan      2014-1-2 2:46
Mary      2014-1-1 12:20
Mary      2014-1-2 12:10
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DateValue` to give you the Date/Time value for midnight.  Then `GROUP BY name` and `DateValue`.

This query returns the earliest time for each person/date combination.  That is not the same as your requested output, but I didn't understand the logic you used to determine which row should be the one returned for each person/date pair.  You may decide you want to base that selection on something other than `Min`, but I think you need to start with a similar `GROUP BY` strategy.

```sql
SELECT
    y.name,
    DateValue(y.[date/time]) AS date_at_midnite,
    Min(y.[date/time]) AS earliest_time
FROM YourTable AS y
GROUP BY
    y.name,
    DateValue(y.[date/time]);
```